# jQuery opacity no show in div

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have this little code but no get show opacity with the function animate of jQuery , i think the code it´s fine but no works , the fail get in animate function opacity :

**This´s my code**

```
$("#slider_zone_infor").css({
    "height":""+show_infor_sliders_h+"px",
    "line-height":""+show_infor_sliders_h+"px"
}).show(100).animate({opacity:1},350);
```

I want show this zone and turn on transparent

Comment: Why show() and animate()? Why not fadeIn()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using :

```
  .hide{
      opacity:0;
  }
```

HTML

```
  <div id="slider_zone_infor" class="hide">
   Hi there
   </div>
```

Then your code will work fine:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var show_infor_sliders_h = "234";
    var show_infor_sliders_h = "200";
    $(document).ready(function(e) {


    $("#slider_zone_infor").css({
    "height":"'"+show_infor_sliders_h+"px'",
    "line-height":"'"+show_infor_sliders_h+"px'"
}).show(100).animate({opacity:1},350);

  });
    </script>
```

If you are using :

```
.hide{
display:none;
}
```

Than this much is ok:

```
$("#slider_zone_infor").css({
    "height":"'"+show_infor_sliders_h+"px'",
    "line-height":"'"+show_infor_sliders_h+"px'"
}).show(100);
```

**Key point:**

You can only do `opacity:0 to opacity:1` and `display:none to display:block,` or you can also use `fadeIn and fadeOut`.

But you can not  do `opacity:0 to display:block`